# C: Structured Data Types - Linked Lists

Tags: c, linked-list

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_node
{
    int data;
    struct list_node *next;
} node;

node *head,*temp;
int counter;

void display_menu();
char get_choice();
void process(char option);

void Insert_first();
void Print_first();
void Delete_first();
void Delete_end();   // Problem
void Insert_end();   // Problem
void Search();

int main()
{
    char choice;

    display_menu();
    do
    {
    choice=get_choice();
    process(choice);
    } while(choice!='J');


    return 0;
}

void display_menu()
{
    printf("What do you want do do?\n");
    printf("A. Insert a node at the beginning of the list\n");;
    printf("B. Delete the first node of the list\n");
    printf("C. Print list\n");
    printf("D. Insert end\n");
    printf("E. Delete the last node of the list\n");
    printf("F. Search\n");


}

char get_choice()
{
    char select;
    printf("Enter your choice:\t");
    scanf("%c",&select);
    getchar();
    printf("\n");

    return select;
}

void process(char option)
{
    switch(option)
    {
        case 'A': Insert_first();break;
        case 'B': Delete_first();break;;
        case 'C': Print_first();break;
        case 'D': Insert_end();break;
        case 'E': Delete_end();break;
        case 'F': Search(); break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid input!\n\n");
    }
}

void Search()
{
    node *a;
    node *b;
    int i, j;

    a=head;
    b=head;
    for(i = 1; i < counter - 1; ++i){
        a = a -> next;
        for(j = i + 1; j < counter; ++j){
            b = b -> next;
            if((a -> data) == (b -> data)){
                printf("0\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("1\n");
            }
        }
    }
    counter++;

}

void Insert_first()
{
    temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    printf("Enter a number:\t");
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    getchar();
    printf("\n");

    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
    counter++;

}

void Insert_end()
{
    temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *x;
    int y;

    printf("Enter a number:\t");
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    getchar();
    printf("\n");

    x=head;
    for(y = 1; y < counter; ++y){
        x=x->next;
    }
    temp->next=x->next;
    x->next = temp;
    counter++;
}

void Print_first()
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
        do
        {
            printf("\t%d\t", temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;
        } while(temp!=NULL);
        printf("\n");
        printf("-------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    }

}

void Delete_first()
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe list is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        head=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        counter--;
    }
}

void Delete_end()
{
    node *x, *z;
    int y;

    if(head == NULL)
        printf("The list is empty");
    else{
        x=head;

        for(y = 1; y < counter; ++y){
            x=x->next;
        }

        z=x;
        x=x->next;
        free(z);
        counter--;
    }
}
```

I have two problems to solve:

1. The `Delete_end()` function;
2. The `Search()` function.

I want the `Delete_end()` function to act as `Delete_first()` function, but instead of deleting the FIRST node and deallocates its space, **it does these to the END node**. I tried to code these functions, but it didnt return what I want it to be.

If we run the codes, and Enter the Following:

[image: Output of the Code]

As you notice when I delete the first node (Switch Choice: B), the list from

```
--------------------------------
   4           3           2
--------------------------------
```

becomes

```
--------------------------------
   3           2
--------------------------------
```

Thus, it deletes the first node and deallocates the space. Now when I delete the end node (Switch Choice: E) and print the list (Switch Choice: C), the list becomes

```
--------------------------------
   3           135704608
--------------------------------
```

I think the number 135704608 is the location in the memory. So what happen here is it didnt delete the last node and deallocates it but instead returns 135704608. I hope you can help me with that.

**Second function is the `Search()`, this function should return 0 if the number is already in the list, else 1 is returned**. Here is the `Search()` function from the above codes:

```
void Search()
{
    node *a;
    node *b;
    int i, j;

    a=head;
    b=head;
    for(i = 1; i < counter - 1; ++i){
        a = a -> next;
        for(j = i + 1; j < counter; ++j){
            b = b -> next;
            if((a -> data) == (b -> data)){
                printf("0\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("1\n");
            }
        }
    }
    counter++;

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For delete at end, your code finds the next to last element and does this:

```
    z=x; // save next to last as z
    x=x->next;  //set last as x
    free(z); // free next to last
```

Instead, I think you want to do something more like this:

```
    free(x->next); // free last elem
    x->next = NULL; // next to last now points to NULL, meaning x is now the last element
```

The problem with your search function is that you never check the first element! You should do your `if` comparison **before** you do `b = b -> next` and then do `a = a -> next` after the inner for loop - otherwise the head will never be compared to anything, and nothing will be compared to the element immediately after it.